# replace punctuation with space in text

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a text like this `Cat In A Tea Cup by New Yorker cover artist Gurbuz Dogan Eksioglu,Handsome cello wrapped hard magnet, Ideal for home or office.`
I removed punctuations from this text by the following code.

```
import string
string.punctuation
def remove_punctuation(text):
    punctuationfree="".join([i for i in text if i not in string.punctuation])
    return punctuationfree
#storing the puntuation free text
df_Train['BULLET_POINTS']= df_Train['BULLET_POINTS'].apply(lambda x:remove_punctuation(x))
df_Train.head()
```

here in the above code `df_Train` is a pandas dataframe in which "BULLET_POINTS" column contains the kind of text data mentioned above.
The result I got is `Cat In A Tea Cup by New Yorker cover artist Gurbuz Dogan EksiogluHandsome cello wrapped hard magnet Ideal for home or office`
Notice how two words `Eksioglu` and `Handsome` are combing due to no space after `,` . I need a way to overcome this issue.

Comment: Do not remove, replace with a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these case, it makes sense to replace all the special chars with a space, and then strip the result and shrink multiple spaces to a single space:

```py
df['BULLET_POINTS'] = df['BULLET_POINTS'].str.replace(r'(?:[^\w\s]|_)+', ' ', regex=True).str.strip()
```

Or, if you have chunks of punctuation + whitespace to handle:

```py
df['BULLET_POINTS'].str.replace(r'[\W_]+', ' ', regex=True).str.strip()
```

Output:

```py
>>> df['BULLET_POINTS'].str.replace(r'(?:[^\w\s]|_)+', ' ', regex=True).str.strip()
0    Cat In A Tea Cup by New Yorker cover artist Gurbuz Dogan Eksioglu Handsome cello wrapped hard magnet  Ideal for home or office
Name: BULLET_POINTS, dtype: object
```

The `(?:[^\w\s]|_)+` regex matches one or more occurrences of any char other than word and whitespace chars or underscores (i.e. one or more non-alphanumeric chars), and replaces them with a space.

The `[\W_]+` pattern is similar but includes whitespace.

The `.str.strip()` part is necessary as the replacement might result in leading/trailing spaces.